# How to build and run examples in OpenGL Superbible 6th edition?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, visual-studio-2013

My system is Win 8.1 64-bit and using VS2013 Express. I can verify my video cards support the latest OpenGL and OpenCL. I used the latest code and media files from authors github and site: https://github.com/openglsuperbible/sb6code and http://www.openglsuperbible.com/example-code/ respectively.

I am able to make debug and release builds of the project(s) successfully but cannot correctly run it either via debug mode or the .exe in the bin folder. A white window will show up and then exit. I was able to step through and found that glfwOpenWindow will return false causing the exit but I cannot step further and see why it is returning so. I found some solutions that suggested changing

```
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

to

```
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, 0);
```

but this does not change my results. I can verify also that major version is 4 and minor is 3 for the book code. I have found a few other people having the same problem but no resolution. Another possible solution (but to a different problem it seems) was changing the project subsystem to Console from Windows but this throws an error regarding main and so it may not be what I'm looking for.

For reference, this book is using glfw version 2.7.6 when (currently) the latest is 3.0.4. I tried swapping this too but it understandably blew up due to all of the changes.

Any further ideas would be great and very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered that while my GPU does support the latest OpenGL, my computer was instead using the integrated Intel HD 4600! By switching my computer to use the dedicated GPU by default, I am able to run the latest OpenGL.

Comment: Lovely! There you go :-)

Answer (score 0):

If it successfully compiled, then please do following:

1. Ensure that you do have the latest graphic card drivers installed (eg. if you have nVIDIA card, go to www.nvidia.com and get newest drivers).
2. Ensure that files which these examples are trying to load (I guess jpg/tga/png files, maybe some obj/fbx/3ds files for geometry, whatever else these examples need) are present at expected path (relative path to exe).
3. Run it as a debug, place breakpoints in app initialization, see that OpenGL is initialized correctly and that required files are loaded. I think you will find that required files are not in expected path(s).

P.S.

I think the best practice for learning OpenGL is not to rely on some library to open window and initalize OpenGL for you - it's better you learn it all step by step - how to open an application window, how to initialize gl render context associated with device context etc. You'd also avoid things like this when you don't know where the problem could be.

Comment: Thanks for the response!
1. I do have the latest drivers which are capable of running the latest OpenGL - it is an Nvidea GTX 760M.

2. These files are int he proper place although I am testing ones that don't have this additional point of failure.

3. When I did this I was getting failure at glfwOpenWindow as mentioned and did not see any errors before this point.

While I agree with your last point and do plan to learn all of the various components, it would still be quite nice for me, and others who bought the book, to quickly be able to run the samples and follow along with the book.